# Edittext getText toString

Tags: android

Below is my EditText and I want to put it input a String tel
The Toast will succeed to show the getText toString
However, I didn't see the value put into tel in LogCat.

```
     edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTel);
     edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {  
         @Override  
         public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {  
            Toast.makeText(Reserve.this, edittext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            tel = edittext.getText().toString();
             return true;  
         }  
     });

     Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);
```

Comment: It will log the output only when you type something and then press the editorAction key, either a Done or next key on softKeyboard.

Comment: Where do you declare `tel` and are you using `tel = ...` anywhere else?

Comment: Thanks and I just declare it as a global variable

Comment: Then your should be able to reference `tel` outside this method. Where are trying to display that LogCat statement?

Answer (score 3):

put `Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);` inside `onEditorAction` method as:

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
Toast.makeText(Reserve.this, edittext.getText().toString(),
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
tel = edittext.getText().toString(); 
Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);
return true;
}
});
```

because maybe possible control is not reached outside  `OnEditorActionListener`

Comment: Simple beacuse when the log is printed, the value of tel is empty string. It only gets fill when u do any action

Comment: because when  `OnEditorActionListener` Listener fire control is not reached out side it .

Comment: I disagree, `tel` is a field variable it can _anywhere_ in the class.  The reason why `tel` is empty is because CYB is using the LogCat statement in a method like `onCreate(), _before_ the user has a chance to change the contents of the EditText.

Comment: @Sam :  then how control reach outside  OnEditorActionListener and how Log statement execute every time  without any action or event who execute this statement if this all code in inside onCreate method? this will execute only once when onCreate method calls

Comment: @Sam : sorry for my English but i think u understand what i want to say?

Comment: We agree that `Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);` must be called after `tel = edittext.getText().toString();`. And I think we agree that `Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);` can be called outside of `onEditorAction()` but it must be called _after_ `onEditorAction()`. Your English is good, but sometimes it's hard to understand. This is great practice. :)

Comment: @Sam : ok i agree with you but if `Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);` is outside `edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { }` block then how this statement executed when `OnEditorActionListener` event fire?

Comment: You are right, if `tel` is outside the editor it won't be called when the editor action happens. But it could be used somewhere else, since `tel` is a field variable.

Comment: @Sam : yes i agree with you .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are just calling a method that stores a reference to an object (of the OnEditorActionListener class) inside the EditText object. The flow continues immediately executing the Log.d() method, printing and empty ¨tel¨. The OnEditorActionListener.onEditorAction() method will be called anytime else, triggered by a user action, and it will execute the code inside it. Maybe the flow could be clearer written like this:

```
OnEditorActionListener listener = new OnEditorActionListener() {  
         @Override  
         public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {  
            Toast.makeText(Reserve.this, edittext.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            tel = edittext.getText().toString();
             return true;  
         }  
     });

edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTel);
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(listener);
Log.d("TEL", "The tel is: "+tel);
```

This way is clearer that the onEditorAction() method is completely independent from the normal flow of execution of that piece of code.